# How Can I make CCTV Web Application using Kurento-media-server?

Tags: camera, webrtc, kurento, fiware-kurento

How Can I make CCTV Web Application using Kurento-media-server? How to show multiple video on single web page?Is this possible or not?Have anyone tried?Please give link or information.I have tried tutorials.Media-Streams of fiware from github but couldn't build it.

## [image]How can I loop multiple stream for multiple cameras?

Comment: https://github.com/AlexxIT/go2rtc .This app can be used to stream multiple cameras.